# How to access docker-machine instances that were created on AWS from new machine

Tags: docker-machine

I set-up some AWS EC2 instances using Docker using docker-machine on my previous laptop, using commands like this:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-instance-type "t2.micro" --amazonec2-security-group MY_SECURITY_GROUP container-1
```

On the old laptop, I can still view and control them:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME                ACTIVE   DRIVER      STATE     URL                       SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
container-1   -        amazonec2   Stopped                                     Unknown    
container-2   -        amazonec2   Running   tcp://xx.xx.xx.xxx:yyyy           v20.10.7   
container-3   -        amazonec2   Stopped                                     Unknown
```

But on my new laptop, I'm not able to see them:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME                ACTIVE   DRIVER      STATE     URL                       SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
```

I have the AWS environment variables (key/secret) on the new laptop. I've looked at the hidden files in the old laptop to see if there's something that docker-machine uses to store a list of created containers, but I don't see anything.

Is there a command to add these to the new laptop, so I can see and start/stop them?

Comment: This isn't a solution, but I found that the keys themselves are listed in the AWS console under EC2>Network & Security>Key Pairs. This is useful for deleting the old key pairs, docker-machine won't allow you to re-use a machine name if keys exist for it.

There is an option to import key pairs there, so perhaps there's some way to generate new key pairs and manually add them.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Rob in that case, I think most of the questions tagged `docker-machine` would also have to be removed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-machine, since `docker-machine` isn't a programming language.

Comment: I completely agree and will start working on that now.

Comment: @Rob the page that lists what you can ask about (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says that _software tools commonly used by programmers_ is a valid topic for SO. One could describe `docker-machine` as a software tool that's commonly used by programmers, so by that definition, it is on-topic for SO. On the other hand, `docker-machine` is *not* *nix-specific, so I'm not sure the the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange is the right place for it.

Comment: Ubuntu is a common tool, also, but that question will get shutdown and deleted here quickly. Don't be looking for loopholes. It's not programming related.

Comment: Ubuntu is a Linux OS - I completely see how questions around it belong in Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. I genuinely don't agree that questions around `docker-machine` belong there, because it's not *nix-specific. If you have the permissions to migrate the tag, I can't stop you, but it does open a can of worms, since there are a _lot_ of other popular SO tags that are in a similar category - `docker-swarm`, `kubernetes`, `amazon-ec2`...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. You need to manually copy the the machine's hidden directory (from `~/.docker/machine/machines/`) on the old laptop to the new one. In the example above, that would be  `~/.docker/machine/machines/container-1`, `~/.docker/machine/machines/container-2`, etc.

In addition, each machine has a config.json that contains absolute paths to the certificates. That config file looks something like this:

```
{   
    "ConfigVersion": 3,
    "Driver": {
        "IPAddress": "4.94.173.4",
        "MachineName": "container-1",
        "SSHUser": "ubuntu",
        "SSHPort": 22,
        "SSHKeyPath": "/Users/USERNAME/.docker/machine/machines/zhxw-production-2/id_rsa",
        "StorePath": "/Users/USERNAME/.docker/machine",
...
```

... where USERNAME is your system username. If this username is different between old and new laptops, you'll need to update all the references to the new paths.